# Find the number of special characters in my Character array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count how many special characters are there in my Character array.

This is my code so far:

```
String s = "hi .this :) is test +line";
int len = s.length();
Character[] array = new Character[len];

for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) 
{   
     if(array[i]==' ' || array[i]==':'  || array[i]=='.' || array[i]=='\'' || array[i]=='\"' || array[i]==')')
     special_chars++
}
```

Comment: What exactly is considered to be a special character?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the methods of `Character` class.

```
if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(array[i]) && !Character.isWhitespace(array[i]))
    special_chars++;
```

`Character.isLetterOrDigit` checks if the char is a letter or a digit. If it is none, then it certainly is a special character!

Comment: i think the method name is self explanatory :)

Comment: I suppose that depends on what the definition of a special character is. For example, is a hyphen or a comma considered to be a special character?

Comment: @svarog Yes It is. But I thought that without it, it would seem that I have not explained my answer!

Comment: what if the char is a whitespace ? i wouldn't consider that char "special"

Comment: @svarog - I'd tend to agree...unfortunately the question as given wasn't very clear in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `String` of your special characters, loop through every character in your input, and check if it's in the `String` of special characters. Something like,

```
String s = "hi .this :) is test +line";
String spec = " :.'\")";
int special_chars = 0;
for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (spec.indexOf(ch) > -1) {
        special_chars++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `BitSet`, you can efficiently set and check indexed binary information (in your case: whether a given character is special or not), so compared to other solutions in this thread you don't need to loop over the set of special characters:

```
BitSet specialCharacters = new BitSet();
specialCharacters.set(' ');
specialCharacters.set(':');
specialCharacters.set('.');
specialCharacters.set('\'');
specialCharacters.set('\"');
specialCharacters.set(')');

String text = "hi .this :) is test +line";
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    if (specialCharacters.get(c)) {
        // special character detected
    }
}
```